# NameError when using input() with Python 3.4

Tags: python, command, command-prompt, nameerror

I am a new Python user and I have been working through a number of tutorials. This has included running some of the code from the Command Prompt. This worked fine  when I first tested the code but for some reason it seems to have stopped working and I am now getting errors when using Input(). I have included the code below and the error message I am receiving.

Code:

```
   import sys
print (sys.version)

print("hello world")
myName = input("What is your name?")
print(myName)

if (myName == "Matt"):
    print("Matt is great!")
elif (myName == "Bob"):
    print("Bob is ok")
else:
    print("Hello world")

input("Press enter to continue")
```

Error Message:

```
C:\Users\matt.xxxx>cd C:\Python34\Scripts\Projects

C:\Python34\Scripts\Projects>helloworld.py
2.7.7 (default, Jun  1 2014, 14:21:57) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
hello world
What is your name?Matt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\Projects\helloworld.py", line 6, in <module>
    myName = input("What is your name?")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Matt' is not defined

C:\Python34\Scripts\Projects>
```

I know this can occur when using older versions of python, however I have checked and I am fairly sure I am using version 3.4 (checked using import sys etc.). I have recently installed PyCharm which is the only thing I can think of that has changed. The code works in PyCharm and from IDLE but not from the Command Prompt. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of - `import sys; print(sys.version)` inside your script?

Comment: Hi Anand. Thanks for your quick response. When I run the code with print(sys.version) it does actually say 2.7.7??? However this isn't the case when I check the version when loading Python from the Command Prompt. Does this make sense. I had no idea I even had 2.7.7 on my machine! Do you know how to ensure 3.4 is used?

Comment: what is the exact command you are using to run the script?

Comment: And what is the result of `echo %PATH%` in your command prompt

Comment: Code and output have been updated

Comment: Anand you are right! I added version 3.4 to the default applications for ext .py files and it is now using version 3. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Cool, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example , I believe you are running the script using - `helloworld.py` - this would cause Windows to lookup the default application associated with the extension `.py` and run it.

I am guessing in your case when you installed PyCharm, it somehow made Python 2.7.7 the default application for `.py` files (Or it was like that from the start) so when you directly run `.py` files (even from command prompt) they run using Python 2.7.7 .

You said in your comment that when running `python` directly from command prompt, you are getting python 3.4 , so the easiest way to fix your issue would be to use that to run your script.

Run it using the command -

```
python helloworld.py
```

As a long term solution, you may want to consider changing the default application associated with `.py` files. You can checkout [this link](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-associate-file-type-or-protocol-program) for guide on how to do that